# Three.js thicker BoxHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

I created a `THREE.BoxHelper` like so:

```js
let bbox = new THREE.BoxHelper(object, 0xff0000);
scene.add(bbox);
```

When I load this up, it looks as expected:

[image: img]

The only thing that I would want to do is make the lines a little thicker. I am aware that this is not directly possible because they are set to `1px`, but I am looking for the quickest way I could do this.

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat

Comment: @Marquizzo, Thank you! But is this their simplest method? In a perfect world, it would be ‘helped.lineHeight’

Comment: All the Three.js helpers use WebGL.line, which is limited to 1px. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/lineWidth There’s nothing that can be done to change this value, so the Threejs people came up with a workaround to get thick lines through another method.